# Run-time permission of Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

Such a new and awesome security functionality is **RUN-TIME Permission**

I am trying to understand it and make one demo for that But one question raise in my mind that when i am at handle user permission with DIALOG.

How to handle "**Never ask Again**"

[image]

Suppose my application MUST need Location/contact but user DENY it with "NEVER ASK AGAIN".

What can i do for that. Not all User understand my field is required.

ANY SUGGESTION?

Comment: I have created library for it. It is easy to use by simple steps. https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/Ask-Permission

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 5):

First you need to implement `OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback` `Listener` of `ActivityCompat` class in your `Activity` and override  `void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)` Method to check whether User is allowing or denying the permission

You can do like this. Here i check for permission access for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`:

```
int REQUEST_STORAGE = 1;

private void checkPermissions() {
    if (hasStoragePermissionGranted()) {
        // you can do whatever you want
    } else {
        requestPermission();
    }
}

public boolean hasPermissionGranted(){
        return  ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

public void requestPermission() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_STORAGE);
    }
}
```

Here is `onRequestPermissionsResult()` method will be called when user allow or deny Permission from Runtime permission dialog.

You can also handle situation when User has checked never show Runtime Permission dialog for that you can show Snackbar or button to redirect user to your application settings page as you can not show permission dialog after user has checked `"Never ask again"`.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_STORAGE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
               //Storage permission is enabled
               canSendAttachments = true;
               systemLogsCheckbox.setEnabled(true);
            } else if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivtity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                //User has deny from permission dialog
                Snackbar.make(mainLayout, getResources().getString("Please enable storage permission"),
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                        .setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_STORAGE);
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
            } else {
                // User has deny permission and checked never show permission dialog so you can redirect to Application settings page
                Snackbar.make(mainLayout, getResources().getString("Please enable permission from settings"),
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                        .setAction("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", MainActivity.this.getPackageName(), null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here i have used `Snackbar` to show relevant message to user about Permission and `mainLayout` is id of `Activity's Main Layout`.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: tx for suggestion, i am already implement it , but what i am say that suppose  user click     deny but my app must required location    than what can i do?? how to Convince user ?

Comment: You give explanation to user why this permission is required by app. you also give situation that what happens if user not allowed permission

Comment: @VishalPatel yes app will not work if permission is must needed

Comment: @VishalPatel If the user selects 'never ask again' your permission has been denied permanently and it can only be enabled through android settings.
If the permission is key for you app, I'd suggest you use 'priming' messages prior asking the permission. You could show a priming dialog (or full screen view) to make the user aware why you need the permission and what happens to the app functionality if it's not granted. After that you can request the permission. 


Take a look at this library https://github.com/aitorvs/allowme that implements also simple priming dialogs.

Comment: I have created library for it. It is easy to use by simple steps. https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/Ask-Permission

Answer (score 2):

I have created a `library` that handle all the `permissions` for you. you can find it in here:

[PermissionHelper](https://github.com/k0shk0sh/PermissionHelper)

---

To answer your question:

in order for you to know if the user `checked` never show again you'll have to check against two things, if the permission is **`declined`** and no **`explanation needed`** if these two returned `**true**` that means that the permission is no longer available to be asked again and the only solution to handle this case is to open the settings screen.

**P.S:** the library i created handle all these kind of scenarios for you and returns callbacks for you to decide what to do next!. the library has two implementations

1. Manual implementation (which mean you'll have to implement the callback in your activity and listen to the returned callback from the library).
2. Let the library request the permission for you and it'll as well return you a callback to let you decide what happens when the permission is permanently  denied.

Answer (score 1):

open your app setting when user chose "Nerver ask again"

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING);
```

my example to handle RuntimePermission:
https://github.com/henrychuangtw/RuntimePermission

Answer (score 0):

### Use [Dexter](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter) library

### or

### Use PermissionsDispatcher:

Step 1 : use [PermissionsDispatcher](http://hotchemi.github.io/PermissionsDispatcher/) library by [hotchemi](https://github.com/hotchemi/) (the library is annotation based, simple to use and well documented)

Step 2 : you have to provide 4 annotated methods and one of them is @OnNeverAskAgain(Manifest.permission.[permission_you_want]) as below

```
@OnNeverAskAgain(Manifest.permission.[permission_you_want])
void showNeverAsk() {  
   // handle here
}
```

Here is [sample](https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/permissions/dispatcher/sample/MainActivity.java)